# How to make the expanded data expand above the row in Vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

```
        <v-data-table 
          items-per-page.sync="-1"
          :headers="headers"
          :items="this.$store.state.results['Some Column']"
          hide-default-footer
          :expanded.sync="expanded"
          show-expand
          item-key="name"
        >
          <template v-slot:[`item.data-table-expand`]="{ item, isExpanded, expand }">
            <v-icon @click="expand(false)" v-if="item.subcategories.length && isExpanded">mdi-chevron-up</v-icon>
            <v-icon @click="expand(true)" v-if="item.subcategories.length && !isExpanded">mdi-chevron-down</v-icon>
          </template>
          <template v-slot:expanded-item="{ item }">
            <td></td>
            <td class="pt-2 pl-8 second-level-data">
              <p v-for="subcategory in item.subcategories"
                :key="subcategory"
              >{{ subcategory.name }}</p>
            </td>
            <td class="pt-2 second-level-data" v-for="year in years" :key="year">
              <p v-for="subcategory in item.subcategories" :key="subcategory">{{ subcategory[year] }}</p>
            </td>
            <td></td>
          </template>
        </v-data-table>
```

Currently, when the row is expanded, the data is being shown below it. How can I show the data above the row which is being expanded when the expand icon is clicked?

Comment: Doesn't seem possible to customize Vuetify's v-data-table that way.  At least nothing in the API suggests it's possible.

Comment: @yoduh I figured out an alternative solution though. But it uses a lot of Javascript so I am hesitant in using that because of memory issues.